# Error Using ORDER BY and GROUP BY Together

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by, sql-order-by

i have a query that is below:

```
SELECT
    o.ordernum,
    o.SCHEDATTEMPT,
    o.lastcontactdate, 
    MAX(OE.NextContactDate) AS NextContactDate
FROM orderevents OE
FULL outer join orde_ o 
ON o.ORDERID=oe.OrderId
WHERE  O.lastcontactdate is not null and SCHEDULED is null and DROPTIME is null      
ORDER by O.LASTcontactdate
```

When i execute this query i get the error `Column 'orde_.ORDERNUM' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`.

What am i doing wrong in this query?

Comment: @MitchWheat how can i resolve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says it all, but its meaning is easier to understand if you see it.

Using an aggregate function in your select list (i.e. `MAX(OE.NextContactDate)`), aggregate functions need to contain all entries in your select list...

```
SELECT
    MAX(o.ordernum),        -- technically contained in an aggregate function - setting aside that it's probably not what you want otherwise
    MAX(o.SCHEDATTEMPT),    -- same
    MAX(o.lastcontactdate), -- same
    MAX(OE.NextContactDate) AS NextContactDate
FROM orderevents OE
FULL outer join orde_ o 
ON o.ORDERID=oe.OrderId
WHERE  O.lastcontactdate is not null and SCHEDULED is null and DROPTIME is null
ORDER by MAX(o.lastcontactdate)
```

...*or* entries in your select list that are not contained by aggregate functions need to be in a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    o.ordernum,
    o.SCHEDATTEMPT,
    o.lastcontactdate, 
    MAX(OE.NextContactDate) AS NextContactDate
FROM orderevents OE
FULL outer join orde_ o 
ON o.ORDERID=oe.OrderId
WHERE  O.lastcontactdate is not null and SCHEDULED is null and DROPTIME is null
GROUP BY o.ordernum, o.SCHEDATTEMPT, o.lastcontactdate -- added GROUP BY clause
ORDER by o.lastcontactdate
```

I suspect you really want the second fix - to add a `GROUP BY` clause to your query.

Comment: when i use first query i give again same error msg `Column "orde_.LastContactDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because ....`

Comment: @A.Goutam: Good catch. Sorry about that. Yes, when you wrap a column in an aggregate function in a select list (e.g. `MAX(o.lastcontactdate)`), the column cannot be "unwrapped" (i.e. `o.lastcontactdate`) in an `ORDER BY` clause. It must be wrapped in the aggregate function just as it is in the select list. I updated the first query accordingly.